# What is the correct way to model time series data when replacing time with a measurement of distance?

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, model

Suppose I have time series data where I have sampled 10 individual objects (of the same kind) from 10 different populations (giving a total of 100 samples). Each of these objects has a centralized accretion point from which it grows, we will call the "center". Using the same axis for each individual object, I drew a line from the "center" (distance 0) to the edge (distance n, different individuals are of different lengths) of each object. Along this line, I measured the concentration of 7 substances to see how they change over time, and if there are differences between the 10 populations. Concentrations were measured every 2.5mm (so in 2.5mm increments). This is technically time series data, as growth (and the concentration of the substances) away from the "center" are a function of time, but I have distance in 2.5mm increments as a predictor instead of literal time. If I want to use time series analysis methods, how would I specify the start, end, and frequency arguments when modeling this data in R?

Here is an example of what it looks like when I plot `Substance1` against distance for one individual using ggplot
[image]

Comment: Is this really spatial data? If it is distance along a line, the difference from a time series is the lack of direction, left-right or right-left does not matter, while the arrow of time matters.